# Getting an android app to keep it's OpenGL Context after hitting the home button

Tags: android, surfaceholder, android-homebutton

First a bit of context: I'm developing a video game for both the Android and iPhone platforms.  The way the iPhone works, when a user hits the home button and returns to the game later, in most circumstances the game will pick up RIGHT where it left off with no hicups.  I immediately jump back into my rendering and game loop.  Setting this up on the iOS platform was absolutely easy for me to do.  Accomplishing this on the Android has left me in a fit of rage after hours of wrestling with google results :P

I have my own OpenGL setup for both the iPhone and Android, and everything has been working great.  The root of the problem, I believe, is that I need a SurfaceHolder to create an OpenGL Context.  Here's the sucky part, when the screen loses focus of the game (ie the home button was hit), Android calls surfaceDestroyed in my SurfaceView class and basically KILLS my opengl context.  I *could* recreate a new one with a new SurfaceHolder when surfaceCreated is called, but then I need to reload all of my art assets which defeats the purpose of everything I'm trying to accomplish.

Can I somehow prevent the Android OS from killing my surface holder, is there some sort of custom view I can use to get this to work?  Is there some setting in the Manifest that can help me out here (I doubt it as I have thoroughly tested most of the flags)?  I know this is possible because Angry Birds does this perfectly on the Android OS.

Comment: I believe your problem isn't with OpenGL context. Destroying the surface view is the right thing to do. You have to create a new one. What do you mean by you're forced to reload all your art assets? You could probably lasy load your art assets so you don't really have to care about it. And you recreate a new opengl context every time your context is destroyed. Having a opengl context open even if the application is in background could have a bad effect on battery life anyway.

Comment: How do I "lasy load" my assets?

Comment: Is there a way to keep my art assets in memory, recreate my OpenGL context when the user comes back, then have my context point to those assets?  I've tried that, but with no success.  I kept getting EGL_BAD_SURFACE errors.